# Updating a column of type double using select and update

Tags: java, mysql, sql, double

I have a column in table account that i have defined as double. I want to update the field which i am calling `account_balance`.

This is my code

```
Query theQuery2 = currentSession.createSQLQuery("update account set account_balance =
    (select account_balance from account where telephone_number = ?4 AND nid_number = ?5) + ?6 where telephone_number = ?4 AND nid_number = ?5") ;
theQuery2.setParameter(6, the_loss);
theQuery2.setParameter(5, nid_number);
theQuery2.setParameter(4, telephone_number);
theQuery2.executeUpdate();
```

This is the mysql query

```
update account
    set account_balance = (select account_balance where telephone_number = ?4 AND nid_number = ?5) + ?6
```

How can i have this query

```
(select account_balance where telephone_number = ?4 AND nid_number = ?5)
```

give me a value that is of type `double` so that i add with the prepared value ?6 which is of type double in java?.

Comment: Your subquery does not make sense to me, because there is not table being selected.  Can you add sample data for all tables involved here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but I guess you actually want to execute `update account set account_balance = account_balance + ? where telephone_number = ? AND nid_number = ?`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have updated the select query

Comment: @JBNizet the current account_balance value exists in the account table thus why i am doing a select inside an update query.

Comment: Your update is doing a blanket change to the _entire_ table (there is no `WHERE` clause).  Is this really what you want to be doing here?  Probably, you intended to correlate the outer query with the subquery via one or more columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the update query with the necessary where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
update account
    set account_balance = (select account_balance where telephone_number = ?4 AND nid_number = ?5) + ?6
```

Does not really make sense.  Presumably, you intend:

```
update account
    set account_balance = account_balance + ?6
    where telephone_number = ?4 and nid_number = ?5;
```

In other words, the filter goes on the `update` and the nested `select` is unnecessary.

You don't really need to worry about types.  You are passing in values as parameters and if the parameter is of a number type (i.e. supports addition), then it will be added to the `account_balance`.

I will say that monetary amounts should be stored using `numeric`/`decimal` (i.e. fixed point values) rather than double (floating point values).